# UITableView not displaying data properly

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

So i have been trying to fix this from day before yesterday but had no luck. I have a UITableView which has nine cells, the problem is when my table view is displayed it displays data only for the first 6 cells, which are visible on screen, after some reading i got to know that i should be reloading the section and not just `[tableview reload]` because it only reloads cells that are visible on the screen, i tried that but it didn't solve the issue. This is how my UITableView looks like:

[image: As you can notice the last cell and the cells below it have no start and end dates.]

After scrolling,
[image]

If i scroll back up fast the first cell becomes empty, i.e there are no start and end dates but now the last cell has start and end dates.
[image]

The last cell now has start and end dates.
[image]

Also if i scroll till the end and then click cancel and again make this view appear all the cells have start and end values. I have no clue why this is happening. Any help will be greatly appreciated. My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` is as:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView1  cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *Cell;

if(indexPath.section == 1)
{
    NSArray *nib = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"StageCloseCell" owner:self options:nil];
    if(indexPath.row == 0)
    {
        Cell = [tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"CloseCell"];

        if (readOnly || [dealStagesFeature isEqualToString:@"VIEW"])
        {
            [closedNoDecisionBtn setHidden:YES];
            [closedLostBtn setHidden:YES];
            [closedWonBtn setHidden:YES];
        }

        if ([dealSelected.stage isEqualToString:@"Closed Won"] ||
            [dealSelected.stage isEqualToString:@"Closed Lost"] ||
            [dealSelected.stage isEqualToString:@"Closed-NoDecision"])
        {
            [closedNoDecisionBtn setHidden:YES];
            [closedLostBtn setHidden:YES];
            [closedWonBtn setHidden:YES];
        }

        if (Cell == nil)
        {
            Cell = (UITableViewCell *)[nib objectAtIndex:0];
            closeDateTxtFld.text = [formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:dealCloseDt];
            //[self enableCloseButtons];
            if([dealSelected.import_source_type isEqualToString:@"SALESFORCE"])
                [closedNoDecisionBtn setHidden:YES];
            [closeLbl setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
 return Cell;
}

StageCell *cell = (StageCell*)[tableView1 dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil)
{
    cell = [[StageCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

if(indexPath.row == 9)
    [cell.contentView addSubview:cell.mClosedSegCtrl];

AppDelegate *app = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

A2OTemplateStage *stage = [stages objectAtIndex:[indexPath row]];

NSLog(@"Deal Stage  = %@",stage);

[[cell mStageNameLbl] setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",stage.stage_name]];

[[cell mStartDateTextField] setTag:START_DATE_TEXTFIELD_CELL_TAG*([indexPath row]+1)];
[cell mStartDateTextField].delegate = self;
[[cell mEndDateTextField] setTag:END_DATE_TEXTFIELD_CELL_TAG*([indexPath row]+1)];
[cell mEndDateTextField].delegate = self;
[[cell mSatusLbl] setTag:COMPLETE_BTN_TAG*([indexPath row]+1)];
[[cell mCompleteBtn] setTag:COMPLETE_BTN_TAG*([indexPath row]+1)];
[[cell mCompleteBtn] addTarget:self action:@selector(satgeComplete:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
[[cell mSkipBtn] setTag:SKIP_BTN_TAG*([indexPath row]+1)];
[[cell mSkipBtn] addTarget:self action:@selector(stageSkip:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];

cell.selectionStyle=UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
//cell.accessoryType=UITableViewCellAccessoryCheckmark;

return cell;
}
```

**EDIT **

```
-(void) reloadControls :(BOOL) disableAll
{
// int noOfStages = validStageCount;
if(!mStagesArr || [mStagesArr count]==0 || [mStagesArr count] < validStageCount)
    return;

for(int i=0; i<validStageCount; i++)
{
    StageData *stageData = mStagesArr[i];
    StageCell *cell = (StageCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:i inSection:0]];
    UITextField *startField = [cell mStartDateTextField];
    UITextField *endField = [cell mEndDateTextField];

    [startField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [endField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    [startField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    [endField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];

    if(stageData.state == stageSkip)
    {
        cell.accessoryType = UITableViewCellAccessoryNone;
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setHidden:NO];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setText:@"Skipped"];
        [startField setText:@""];
        [startField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
//      [startField setPlaceholder:@"Start Date"];
        [startField setPlaceholder:[formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:stageData.startDate]];
//          [endField setPlaceholder:@"End Date"];
        [endField setText:@""];
        [endField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
        continue;
    }
    if(stageData.state == stageInProgress)
    {
        if(readOnly)
        {
            [cell.mSatusLbl setHidden:NO];
            [cell.mSatusLbl setText:@"In Progress"];
            [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
            [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        }
        else
        {
            [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:NO];
            [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:NO];

            if([stageData.startDate compare:[NSDate date]] == NSOrderedDescending)
                [cell.mCompleteBtn setEnabled:NO];
            [cell.mSatusLbl setHidden:YES];
        }
    }
    if(stageData.state == stageComplete)
    {
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setHidden:NO];
        //[cell bringSubviewToFront:cell.mSatusLbl];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setText:@"Completed"];
        [startField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0f green:220/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
        [endField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0f green:220/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
        [startField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [endField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
    }
    if(stageData.state == stageFuture)
    {
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setHidden:YES];
    }
    [startField setPlaceholder:[formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:stageData.startDate]];
    [startField setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:220/255.0f green:220/255.0f blue:220/255.0f alpha:1.0]];
    if(stageData.state == stageComplete)
    {
        [endField setText:@""];
        [endField setPlaceholder:[formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:stageData.endDate]];
    }
    else
    {
        [endField setText:[formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:stageData.endDate]];
        [endField setPlaceholder:@""];
    }
    if(readOnly)
    {
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        [startField setEnabled:NO];
        [startField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [endField setEnabled:NO];
        [endField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [closedLostBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closedWonBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closedNoDecisionBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closeLbl setHidden:NO];
        [closeLbl setText:[self dealCloseStatus]];
        [closeDateTxtFld setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [closeDateTxtFld setEnabled:NO];
    }
    if(disableAll)
    {
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setEnabled:NO];
        [cell.mSatusLbl setEnabled:NO];
        [startField setEnabled:NO];
        [endField setEnabled:NO];
        [closeDateTxtFld setEnabled:NO];
//      [closeDateTxtFld setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [closeDateTxtFld setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [closedLostBtn setEnabled:NO];
        [closedWonBtn setEnabled:NO];
        [closedNoDecisionBtn setEnabled:NO];

        continue;
    }

    if ([dealStagesFeature isEqualToString:@"VIEW"])
    {
        [cell.mCompleteBtn setHidden:YES];
        [cell.mSkipBtn setHidden:YES];
        [startField setEnabled:NO];
        [startField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [endField setEnabled:NO];
        [endField setTextColor:[UIColor blackColor]];
        [closedLostBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closedWonBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closedNoDecisionBtn setHidden:YES];
        [closeLbl setHidden:YES];
        [closeDateTxtFld setTextColor:[UIColor grayColor]];
        [closeDateTxtFld setEnabled:NO];
    }
}

closeDateTxtFld.text = [formatterForDisplay stringFromDate:dealCloseDt];
//[self enableCloseButtons];
}
```

**EDIT (Answer)**
The problem was solved by calling the method `reloadControls` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`. All thanks to ThXou.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the point is, every time you scroll down or up, the tableView is reloading and reusing the cells. So, you should enable/disable, hide/unhide the UI components in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` for the section 0 in order to tell the reused cells which views it must show. Just like you do in section 1.

However, subclassing UITableViewCell and implementing that kind of behaviour inside the subclass, I think is a best practice and will help you to organize your code better.

Comment: you mean the code for setting the start and end date should be inside `cellForRowAtIndexPath` ?

Comment: `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` is telling the tableView which cell it should put in a specific indexPath, so you must tell the tableView, not only the cell, but the content of the cell too. Where are you setting up the start and end date?

Comment: i have a separate method, do you want to have a look at that code ?

Comment: Ok. As I said, you should call `reloadControls:` in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` in order to reload the controls when the cells are being reused. Try it and tell us what happen.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107703/discussion-between-tkutal-and-thxou).